# Can you use the Windows 7 WAIK and procedure to image Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, imaging, waik

Can you use the Windows 7 WAIK and procedure to image Vista?

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to use the WAIK that applies to the operating system in question.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the WAIK for 7 work on Vista just fine. You'd have to be more specific as to what you're trying to accomplish. Vista didn't have all the features Win7 does, using a newer tool doesn't add those features.